# Display data from database in a many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

So I have two classes called Student and Classroom. It is a many to many relationship so my model is

```
class Student< ApplicationRecord
  has_many :student_classrooms
  has_many :classrooms, :through => :student_classrooms
end

class Classroom< ApplicationRecord
  has_many :student_classrooms
  has_many :students, :through => :student_classrooms
end

class StudentClassroom< ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :classroom
end
```

My controller in Student is

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @student = Student.new    
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(course_params)
    if @student.save
      flash[:success] = "Student created!"
      redirect_to @student
    end
  end

  def show
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @name = @student.name
    #@classroom = Classroom.find_by(name: @name) <--
  end
  ...

end
```

My question is how do I get the classroom locations of a student and store it into a variable so I am able to show it on a webpage.

Comment: Were neither answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  def show
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @name = @student.name
    @classrooms = @student.classrooms
  end
```

That'll give you an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which you can do further `where` statements on. Or, you could use it in your view to iterate and show all the student's classrooms.

Mark has it right, in your `show.html.erb` you can do something like:

```
  <% @classrooms.each do |classroom| %>
    <%= classroom.name %>
  <% end %>
```

If you want something more than just the name (like maybe the classroom number), I would recommend going with a `_classroom.html.erb` partial. Which you would use something like:

```
  <% @classrooms.each do |classroom| %>
    <%= render partial: 'classroom', locals: {classroom: classroom} %>
  <% end %>
```

I would also recommend spending a few minutes and learning/converting to HAML. So, you can have a `show.html.haml` file that looks more like:

```
  - @classrooms.each do |classroom|
    .classroom-container{id: classroom.id}
      = render partial: 'classroom', locals: {classroom: classroom}
```

Or, for Mark's example:

```
%ul
  - @classrooms.each do |classroom|
    %li 
      = classroom.name
```

Isn't that much prettier? And, you save yourself all that hassle of typing out annoying erb syntax. And no having to remember to close tags! HAML is full of rainbows and smells like cotton candy!

Comment: how do i get the value of the column, do i use `@student.classrooms.name`

Comment: You need to do `@student.classrooms.pluck(:name)` @Asad

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you need to do `pluck` here. I don't suspect pulling all the columns is going to create that much overhead and then, like you said, you end up with an array which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your show method:

```
def show
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @name = @student.name
  @classrooms = @student.classrooms
end
```

Then in your `app/views/students/show.html.erb` file, you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
  <% @classrooms.each do |classroom| %>
    <li><%= classroom.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This would print all the classroom names for the student you are viewing as an unordered list.